# ActiveMQ do not receive entity with blob property

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I am trying to use ActiveMQ for queueing in a Spring Boot application. Following is my entity:

```
public class AuditLogModel implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long logId;
private String description;
private Mode mode;
private String enitityKeyValue;
@Transient
private String oldValue;
@Transient
private String newValue;
@Lob
private Blob oldData;
@Lob
private Blob newData;
private Date accessTime;
private String userId;
private String entityType;
}
```

As you can see I have two properties of type Blob in my entity.

I also have following JMS listener:

```
@JmsListener(destination = queue)
public void receiveMessage(final AuditLogModel jsonMessage) throws JMSException {
    auditLogModelService.save(jsonMessage);
}
```

The issue is that my listener do not receive any data added to the queue even when am not setting any data to these properties. But if I remove the properties of type Blob from the entity the listener works fine.

What could be wrong in my code?

Comment: this might help http://activemq.apache.org/blob-messages.html

Comment: @Vihar i tried it, but i could not send a json data as blob message. i have a very large data, so i can only save the data as blob in db. thats why am trying this.